# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un campo de texto despues de un evento keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypressevent

Estoy realizando una validación con `regex` por caracteres:

**Condición de las expresiones regulares**

```
const regex = {
  texto: /^[a-zA-Z\áéíóú\s]+$/,
  alfanumerico: /^[a-zA-Z\áéíóú\s0-9]+$/,
  numeros: /^[\d]+$/
}
```

- Capturo el carácter mediante un evento `.keypress()`, el cual me permite usar el método `.preventDefault()` para evitar escribir dentro del campo de texto si no coincide la validación.

**Evento `.keypress()`**

```
$('#texto').keydown(function(e) {
    char_validate(regex.texto, e, $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**Función `.char_validate()`**

```
const char_validate = (_regex, e, id_element) => {
let char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
if (!_regex.test(char)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(`#${id_element}`).parents(".formulario__grupo").addClass("incorrecto");
} else {

}

  console.log(empty_input_validate(id_element));
}

const empty_input_validate = (id_element) => {
   let input_value = $(`#${id_element}`).val()
   let length_value = input_value.length;
   return length_value
}
```

- Busco obtener el `.length` del campo de texto después de haber insertado el carácter.

**Problema:** El problema es que aún habiendo insertado el carácter, envía el valor de 0, cuando debiera ser 1. Busco la forma de solucionarlo, para poder controlar cuando el campo esté vacío.

Comment: Lo mas probable que el evento de validación se haga al mismo tiempo que el de rellenar el input, tal ves podrias intentar con el metodo [keyUp](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Comment: El `.keypress()` me evita escribir si el carácter no es válido. Ahora, el `.keyup()` me permite seguir escribiendo aún y cuando no se cumpla la condición.

Comment: Controla la entrada con el evento _keypress_ y la longitud del campo con otro evento, tal vez _keyup_ o _input_.